# Performance of HTML links

Tags: html, browser

Is there any reason to prefer

```
<a href="alpha/beta.html">
```

over

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/dir/alpha/beta.html">
```

(assuming that the links refer to the same location)? And similarly for references to scripts and style sheets.

I worry that the former might be slightly slower because the browser might reuse a connection in the former case but open a new connection in the latter.

Or are browsers smart enough to handle this in the optimal way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a major reason : **portability**. When something changes, you feel better if it is not hard-written in one thousand places.

Additionnally, the relative form — the first one — is much shorter. So, when you have dozens of internal links in your page, using the relative links saves many bytes. Here is for the **performance**. This gives shorter transfer times, so **it saves energy** and **it is good for the planet Earth**.

Regarding the reuse of connections, the relative or absolute form of the links do not matter. Web browsers don't work that way. Anyway, Web browsers are very good at using relative links and directing them to the good server.

**Relative links** are definitely the way to go.

Comment: Thank you Nicolas and the rest who answered here.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP is a [state less](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateless_protocol) protocol, therefore everytime a user clicks on a link which links to a new HTML page a HTTP request is sent to the server, so using the full URL is not slower or faster than a relative URL.

Comment: That's fine for the <a href=...> link, but what about links to scripts and style sheets which are loaded as part of the page load? If I remember correctly, there is an option in HTTP that allows a browser to keep a connection to a server open for later use.

Comment: There's the keep-alive (http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.1/draft-ietf-http-v11-spec-01.html#Keep-Alive) option in HTTP 1.1 which can be used to achieve something like this, but it's not in common use I think. Google tries to enhance HTTP to do parallel HTTP-Requests with their SPDY protocol (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SPDY)

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't any difference in performance in terms of requesting the page to load because they will both resolve to the exact same address, though the page size will be slightly larger with absolute paths by virtue of the src attributes being longer but that is obviously, not worth mentioning unless you have a page with thousands of links on of course.

Relative paths (your first example) are in most cases preferred over absolute as if the domain needs to change, you wont have to go through your entire site updating the image/file paths.